# Hquery radio button always evaluating to true

Tags: jquery, if-statement, radio-button

I have two radio buttons, one with value="true" one with value="false".  When I try to use the value in an if statement, I always get "true" regardless of which is selected.

Can you point out my error?

Form snippet:

```
<p>
            <label class="description" for="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"><?php _e('Do you want the slider to advance automatically?', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?></label>
            <input id="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]T" name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]" type="radio" <?php if($wpbpp_options['slideshow'] == 'true') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="true" />Yes
            <input id="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]F" name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]" type="radio" <?php if($wpbpp_options['slideshow'] == 'false') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="false" />No

         </p>
         <p>   
            <label class="description" for="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"><?php _e('How often do you want the slider to advance (number of seconds)?', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?></label>
            <input id="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]" name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]" type="number" min="1" max="8" step="1" value="<?php echo $wpbpp_options['slideshowSpeed']; ?>"/>
        </p>
```

jquery:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  togglefields();

  $('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').change(function(){ alert (jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').val()); });

});   

  function togglefields() { 
   if (jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').val() =="true") {
      jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"]').show();
      alert ('show');
    } else {
       jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"]').hide();
       alert ('hide');

    }   
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the checked one:

```
jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]:checked').val()
```

Or inside the click handler:

```
this.value
$(this).val()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rW8fH/